# How to disable loopback in a Windows PGM socket?

Tags: c#, networking, multicast, multicastsocket

I'm using the standard Windows PGM socket implementation (also known as the "MSMQ PGM"), with RDM socket type. I have noticed that, as per this [Microsoft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the **MulticastLoopBack** socket option cannot be set.

In other words, the rather familiar syntax:

```
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastLoopback, 0);
```

will throw an invalid argument error.

Is anybody aware of any alternative means to disable multicast loopback on a PGM socket instance? Anything from the cleanest one-liner to a registry hack would be very welcome.

Comment: This is from a private e-mail reply from Mike Rettig, author of Emcaster.
_No, I don't know of an option to disable loopback. If one does not
exist, it could be implemented within the library based upon the
source ip of the message._